# Why does a cypress test freeze when attempting to select an option by its position in the element cy.get() returns?

Tags: javascript, cypress, html-select

I am trying to select an option from the element that cy.get() returns. The element is a dropdown menu and it has an option that is not disables in the array position 1. However, whenever I run the cypress test that is meant to select this option it freezes when it gets to this command. The UI stops updating, the spinning progress wheel does not continue to spin and the test neither succeeds nor fails. I cannot interact with the chrome tab, even to close it, so I used task manager to close it. The webpage says that it ran out of memory, but the test is simpler that others that I have run perfectly fine, so it should have enough memory.

I attempted to use different identifiers of the option(name, value), but those also froze. I tried restarting the cypress application, but to no avail.
This is my code for selecting the option:

```
cy.get('#empty-database-server').select(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `select` function takes in a String or Number representing the `value` of the `option`, or the index of the option. Is there an `<option>` tag with a value of `1`, or more than one `<option>` tag with a value of `1` in the page? Did you want index `0` instead of index `1`?

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/select

Comment: The option is in position 1. Position 0 is not a selectable option so when entered into the select() it fails instead of causing chrome to run out of memory. I also tried select() with the text value of the option and assigned an id to the option to select. Whenever it should have succeeded, it froze chrome by making it run out of memory. I also tried in different browsers and they also froze.